# Thread.Join() doesn't wait until thread terminates

Tags: c#, multithreading, inputstream, streamreader

I'm making a server and when a client connects, I create a thread, that listens to the messages from the client, so basically just does `StreamReader.Readline()`
The thread which creates this `answerListener` thread has to wait until `answerListener` thread terminates, but it doesn't wait.
this is a part of my code

```
            Thread answersListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListeningAnswers));
            answersListener.Name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name + "_listener";
            answersListener.Start();

            while (player.status.Equals(PlayerStatus.Playing))
            {
                CheckOpponentStatus();
                Thread.Yield();
            }

            DetermineResult(player.status);


            answersListener.Join();

            RuntimeInfo.Instance.playerList.TryDequeue(out player);

            player.Input.Close();
            player.Input.Dispose();
            player.Output.Close();
            player.Output.Dispose();
            player.Socket.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("client " + player.playerID + " disconnected");
            player = null;
```

And this is what `StartListeningAnswers()` method does:

```
            while (player.status.Equals(PlayerStatus.Playing))
            {
                answer = player.Input.ReadLine();
                if (answer == null) return;
            }
```

This is a `catch` block in the `StartListeningAnswers()` method:

```
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(player.playerID + " Connected = " + player.Socket.Connected);

            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: ReceiveAnswer from " + player.playerID);
            return;              
        }
```

When I run my server I get an exception while trying to do `ReadLine()` in the `StartListeningAnswers()`
I have the following order in console output:
`client 1 disconnected`
`1 Connected = False`
`ERROR: ReceiveAnswer from 1`

So I guess the main thread doesn't wait until player sends something and simply continues it's execution and closes the stream.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems concerning your code. The first is, you doesn't have the call `Thread.Yield()`. And the `player.status` is not thread safe (http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/c-sharp-threading).

But the main problem is that `player.status` never becomes other than `PlayerStatus.Playing`, so the `while` loop in the server never gets interrupted.

I don't know the context completely and
I would suggest a different way to implement this, but you could do something like:

```
public void StartListeningAnswers()
{
    try
    {

        while (player.status.Equals(PlayerStatus.Playing))
        {
            string answer = player.Input.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( answer )) 
                return;
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        player.status = PlayerStatus.Stopped;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I have `Thread.Yield()` method? I thought `enum` is thread safe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.enum%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) There are two ways to change `player.status`: first in the `StartListeningAnswers()` and the second way is `CheckOpponentStatus` I just deleted this part of code because I thought it has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Nowhere. Windows will handle the threadslices/time. If you like the wait on a thread, you could take a look at `ManualResetEvent`s. They will handle the waiting with less cpu consumption.

Comment: The enum is not a problem, enums are constants (numbers), but the playerstatus variable is.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at `ManualResetEvent` and will make `player.status` thread safe. Thanks for your help, I'll mark your solution as an answer, if this helps.

Comment: I did what you have suggested, but it didn't solve the problem. Could you recommend something else?